# RedirectException: Redirect loop detected

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I'm testing a request to get data from an URL using [dio](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/dio) in my Dart code.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class Api {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  var path = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  void getHttp() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get(path);
      print(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

In this case it brings the result correctly.

But, I actually need get data from this URL:

```
http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbwMPI0sDBxNXAOMwrzCjA0sjIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wNnUwNHfxcnSwBgIDUyhCvA5EawAjxsKckMjDDI9FQE-F4ca/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0KO6H80AU71KG7J0072/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/?timestampAjax=1588600763910
```

Using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) I can access the data:

[image]

So, **the problem is** that, if I try to get data from that URL in my code, I get the following exception error:

```
I/flutter (23393): DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: RedirectException: Redirect loop detected
```

If this URL is redirecting, why is it working when using Postman? Anyway, how could I handle this redirected request in order to access data?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a while, I noticed that the response to this request is coming as HTML and not as Json. So I needed to create a way to get DOM coming from the request, removing HTML tags and encoding string to Json.

Comment: The same problems happens to me that the the response with 302 redirection will cause the Dio throwing exception . How could you fix it ?